# how to save fraction in php-class

Tags: php

I'm not able to save a fraction in a class. This fraction i would use in lots of methods and it should for all object remain the same!
Error-message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ',' or ';' in C:...
```

I tried it in the following way:

```
class Myclass {
    public static $fraction = 1/3;

    // my methods...

}
```

another attempt was:

```
class Myclass {
    public function __construct() {
        public static $fraction = 1/3;
    }
    // my methods... 
}
```

maybe i got the syntax into the class wrong or made another fundamental error..., im not used to OOP...

Comment: Are you sure this is really what you want to do? The value stored would be `0.333333.....`

Answer (score 1):

```
    class Test {

    public static $fraction;
    public function __construct() {
        self::$fraction = 1/3;

    }
}

$class = new Test();
echo $class::$fraction;
```

And here you have explanation that expression can't be used in variable during initialization: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Thanks a lot :-D
Now it seems to be also logical, that it was not possible before…

If I have more constants (for example var2 = 2, var3 `= 3) which I use in the methods for ALL OBJECTS of the class should I save them also in this method or should I save them directly under the class? What is better (possible is both, if there is no fraction which I cant express in decimal)?

Comment: could you provide example. Everythig depends on use case. Also there is difference between constant of class and static property